# Numbering latex presentation - counting problem

Tags: latex

I'm working on a presentation with Latex {beamer}. I have the following problem:

When I use the `itemize` command on a slide in conjunction with `\visible<2->{text}` Latex counts a new page for each item. That's why I have something like 17/11 on my presentation.

Does one know how to solve this problem?

With `\thispagestyle{empty}` I solve the problem only temporarily and not satisfactorily

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark any of the two answers below as accepted, if it solves! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you may not want a new page (slide) for each item in each `itemize` environment in your presentation, for example if you have to print your slides. In this case, you may switch from

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
```

to

```latex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

before compiling again and print your output pdf file (whose page count will now be the same or smaller). The `handout` option is discussed in section 4.6 of this [Beamer User Guide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Don't show the page number, but use the frame number instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item text text
\item text \visible<2->{text}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```